# Permission denied using ssh command in shell

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, scp, sshpass

I'm trying to execute this shell with command line

```
host="192.168.X.XXX"
user="USERNAME"
pass="MYPASS"
sshpass -p "$pass" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/MYPATH/File.import "$user@$host:/"home/MYPATH/
```

To copy a file from my local server in to remote server. The remote server is a copy of the remote server but when I try to execute this shell I have this error:

```
**PERMISSION DENIED, PLEASE TRY AGAIN**
```

I didn't understand why if I try to execute this command in command line is working.

```
USERNAME@MYSERVER:~$ sshpass -p 'MYPASS' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/MYPATH/File.import USERNAME@192.168.X.XXX:/home/MYPATH/
```

Somebody have a solution??

Comment: try looking at this post http://serverfault.com/questions/39733/why-do-i-get-permission-denied-publickey-when-trying-to-ssh-from-local-ubunt

Comment: Maybe try this? sshpass -p "${pass}" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/MYPATH/File.import "${user}@${host}:/home/MYPATH/"

Comment: I've tried your solution but don't change... I've a permission error again!

Answer (score 5):

Please use a pipe or the `-e` option for the password anyway.

```
export SSHPASS=password
sshpass -e ssh user@remote
```

Your simple command with `-e` option:

```
export SSHPASS=password
sshpass -e scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/MYPATH/File.import user@192.168.X.XXX:/home/MYPATH/
```

Please remove the wrong quotes from your command:

```
sshpass -p "$pass" scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /home/MYPATH/File.import $user@$host:/home/MYPATH/
```

You should also be able to remove the quotes around `$pass`.

Please ensure that you have no special characters in your `pass` variable or escape them correctly (and no typos anywhere).

For simplicity use a ssh command instead of scp for testing

Use the `-v` or `-vvv` option for the scp command to check what scp is trying to do. Also check the `secure` log or `auth.log` on the remote server

Comment: Patrick I've tried your solution but I have the same result. Permission denied! My password is easy and don't use special characters! I don't understand why can't copy the file with shell using the same code that I use in the command line! I've tried to copy this code in crontab but no working too.

Comment: I was having the same issue.  Once I removed the quotes around the password, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install "sshpass" command  then use the below snippet

```
export SSHPASS=password
sshpass -e  sftp user@hostname << !
   cd sftp_path
   put filename
   bye
!
```

Answer (score 0):

A gotchya that I encountered was escaping special characters in the password which wasn't necessary when entering it in interactive ssh mode.